# Why my django static file have number in the end

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I have to debug some existing Django project build me other develeopers.

In my local developement environment all the static files have path like

`/static/myapp/module/user.js`

But when i see the html of `testing` on tetsing server then i can see the files like

`static/myapp/module/user.42323gdb.js`

Now i want to know why the system is using that file instead of user.js.

Is there any setting which i can fix or it is meant to do like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your project uses one of the [asset managers](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/). I suspect you can find it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

**UPDATE**: By default the `django-pipeline` does this magic then the `DEBUG = False`.  Which is the case for your development environment.

The other setting to enable/disable the `pipeline` is the [`PIPELINE_ENABLED`](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#pipeline-enabled).  So you can have the "normal" file names on the production server too.  But I suggest you to leave the `pipeline` enabled :-)

Comment: Settings says `pipeline` but thing is  i have same setting in my local machine but they don't get user wkith numbers . it only gets file without numbers . i have those files in folder to be as backup but system uses plane file . but in testing its uses file with numbers.

Comment: The other difference is i have `DEBUG false` in testing . is that can be the case that pipeline works only with DEBUG false and thats why in my local computer. pipeline is not doing anything

Comment: Yes, `DEBUG` is the key for the difference. See the updated answer.